# What is the bounty of Gol D. Roger?

Tags: one-piece

I researched and found Monkey D. Dragon to be worth 850,000,000. But what about Roger?

Comment: There was one entry in the eternal log which had an unreadable bounty for Gol D. Roger. Don't think the bounty was mentioned anywhere else

Comment: Maybe @TGamer meant to ask what was his bounty at the moment of capture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [chapter 957](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_957), titled "Ultimate", it was revealed that **Gol D. Roger's bounty was 5,564,800,000 Berry**, the highest pirate bounties in history.

The partial bounty poster was also shown, although it didn't show the bounty amount.

[image: Gol D. Roger's bounty poster]

Answer (score 4):

The answer to that question, as far as I know, hasn't been revealed yet. His bounty from when he was alive is unknown for now.

For that matter, Dragon's bounty being 850,000,000 is a false rumor, as no official sources have revealed his bounty either. Besides, a bounty this comparatively "low" would contradict Dragon's status as the most wanted man in the world, as Jack and Charlotte Katakuri both have bounties that equal or exceed a billion.